# get row count where user = $_session['username']

Tags: php, sql

I have a table with the columns: `(ID, UserID, Slot, ItemID, Quant)`

Lets say I have a row with values: `('1', '10', '2', '35', '200');`

This row has a slot value of 2. i have twenty slots in an inventory tab. i want to insert data in ascending numerical order. is there a way to write a query where it checks to see the last slot used so it can assign the item to the next slot? so if slot 2 has been used the next item would then consume slot 3.

Or is there a way to compare multiple variables to a numerical value without having to have both variables equal to that number so like

```
if($var1 or $var2 or $var3 == 1) {
excute this code
}
```

instead of doing the following:

```
if($var1 ==1) {
  execute code
}
if($var2 == 1) {
  execute code
}
if($var3 == 1) {
  execute code
}
```

Comment: [`in_array()`](http://nl3.php.net/in_array) possibly with the strict flag or simply `||`.

Comment: Could be wrong without more info, but this sounds like a bad approach to a solution. What is it you are doing with the slots/inventory? You might be better with just using a new row with perhaps an additional column, or changing the approach and somehow using auto increment, but more info is needed to advise

Comment: basicly i have x amount of products which will be displayed in a blocked format where each <td> is assigned to a slot. so im trying to determine which slot to use next based on next number avaliable

Comment: Ok,  still not sure of your setup, but it sounds like you just insert into a new row with your data, then when you query, use `ORDER BY` on a relevant column (maybe need a new one with auto increment) and then loop the query with a `WHILE` and they'll display in order.

Comment: auto increments would be a good idea but the products would difer between userId. so when querying Select itemId FROM Inventory WHERE UserId = $_session['userid'] i wold run into a problem unless each user inserting a row would auto increment from the last row inserted by them.

Comment: Edit your question with a bit more detail. What is the purpose of the UserId, Slot, and ItemID, and what relation do they have with each other. IE each user has their own inventory? Each user shares inventory based on Slot?

Comment: Your subject contains `$_session['username']` – If this is in fact what you're using, **it won't work**. `$_SESSION` is a [**superglobal**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) and **MUST** be in uppercase. `Select itemId FROM Inventory WHERE UserId = $_SESSION['userid']` – also make sure you use `session_start();` also (in all your files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but IMHO your data model is fundamentally broken. There are two possible cases:

- If **and only if** you **never ever** need to access a single slot, i.e. if the slots are a closed entity, you should store a serialized slot structure.
- If you need whatever access to a single slot, I would expect to solve such a problem by having a table `slots` and another table consuming it via a jointable. Using a slot can then simply be acomplished by repeatedly `INSERT`ing, until no more key violations occur (ofcourse there are more efficient ways)

**Edit**

In response to @Stoic's request, here is more elaboration on the second bullet: Assume the following:

- the table in the OQ is called `useritems`
- there is another table called `users`, where `UserID` comes from (PK)
- assume, there is another table called `items`, where `ItemID` comes from (PK)

Now we create a table `userslots`

```
CREATE TABLE userslots (
  UserID int, -- possibly some FK,
  SlotNum int,
  ItemId int, -- possibly some FK,
  ItemCount int,
  -- possibly more, as the game logic needs (Styling, etc.)
  PRIMARY KEY(UserID, SlotNUm),
)
```

and we create a row for every slot of every user in it, with SlotNum=0..N and ItemID=ItemCount=0 - this gives us also the possibility to have different users own a different number of slots.

Now if we want to insert an item, we go two steps:

- Maybe the USer already has such an item and we just need to increase the count? `UPDATE userslots SET ItemCount=ItemCount+1 WHERE UserID=$UserID and ItemID=$ItemID LIMIT 1`. If this returns 1 affected row, we are done.
- If not, we need to use a new slot: `UPDATE userslots SET ItemID=$ItemID, ItemCount=1 WHERE UserID=$UserID and ItemCount=0 LIMIT 1`.
- If we need to remove an Item, we just `UPDATE userslots SET ItemCount=ItemCount-1 WHERE UserID=$UserID and ItemID=$ItemID and ItemCount>0 LIMIT 1`, the number of affected rows (0 or 1) atomically shows us, if the user had such an item at all: No race with another session, that could lead to double-consumption.

Comment: good idea i will construct a new table and process between them thanks.

Answer (score -1):

At least one way to do it in SQL is:

```
SELECT max(slot) FROM table_name;
```

Then you could extract that out from the resultset and then insert into next slot.

And for the if question:

```
if($var1 == 1 || $var2 == 1 || $var3 == 1) {
  do_something();
}
```

Comment: This will break, if two sessions run into the race condition, so you need at least transaction and a retry logic

Answer (score -1):

You can use SQL's `max` function to check the last maximum value for a column, like this:

```
SELECT max(slot) FROM table_name;
```

Then, for the conditions, you can use either of the following:

```
$matrix = array($var1, $var2, $var3);
if (in_array(1, $matrix) {
   execute_code();
}
```

or,

```
if ($var1 == 1 || $var2 == 1 || $var3 == 1) {
   execute_code();
}
```

I would personally prefer the `in_array` method, since that is more versatile and easy to implement.

Comment: This will break, if two sessions run into the race condition, so you need at least transaction and a retry logic

Comment: @EugenRieck: are you sure? I thought, we can use `mysqli::store_result` method and it will always return the result of last query we did. Isnt that thread safe? I only supplied him the SQL query needed, and not the PHP code, so that the OP can use whatever logic he further requires.

Comment: The race is in the SQL: The result of `SELECT max(slot) FROM table_name;` might no longer be valid, at the point of time it is processed (if another session inserted a new item)

Comment: hmm.. agreed... will you update your answer with a probable solution, then? I would like to learn, as well :)

Comment: Just did so, see above or below.